# Run Batch File in Asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, batch-file

I am using asp.net C# 4.0

I have a batch which will open a text file.

Batch File query

```
ECHO OFF
start D:\accounts\request\08__processing\0377e792-4ca9-4550-b78c-de2bdf26611f.txt
```

ASp.net Code

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("D:\\bacthFile.bat");
```

when i double click on the batch file its opening the text file.But when run above code its not opening any notepad.

it is not showing any exception also.

Please Help

Thanks

Comment: Do you run on localhost?

Comment: For what reason? That wont open it in *your* Desktop as the site is running under a different user so can't access your Desktop ...

Comment: Just guessing here... I would think that the ASP.NET code is executed under a different user account (probably with a non-interactive login), which is why nothing is happening in your interactive session when you run it.

Comment: i have host this site at my local iis with my lapy credential

Comment: may be this is the reason.Not Sure

Comment: Please Past above comment as answer so that i can close this question

Comment: Do you want the user of your web app to see the Notepad?

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong way to read a text file from ASP.NET, you need to use System.IO and put files you need to read somewhere where ASP.NET can get at them, eg.. App_data. That said, here is how to do it the wrong way: IIS runs on an invisible virtual window--it's a service. There is a way to get some services to display the UI, I forget how. In any case, you'd have to RDP onto the server, to see such a window after starting the service and goosing it into displaying a UI (this trick might not even work for IIS).

Next, as commenters noted, on IIS, you'll have one set of credentials different from your own (depends on what version of IIS)-- in any case, it will have restricted access and be somewhat sandboxed. If you set up impersonation and windows authentication in the web.config, sometimes you can get your request to run with your credentials.

Next, if the web host runs in medium trust, you might not be able to launch arbitrary apps from the asp.net appdomain.

Finally, the only way this could ever work is if your app is always running locally with casinni (the visual studio development server)-- but in that case, you could simplify things a lot by using a console app instead of asp.net unless you really need the HTML templating, say for output.